# Pandas dataframe how to replace single column with multiple

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

For example I have a dataframe like:

```
col1 col2 col3
0    2    1
```

and I want to replace it so that

```
{0: [a,b], 1: [c,d], 2: [e, f]}
```

So I want to end up with a dataframe like this:

```
col1 col1b col2 col2b col3 col3b
a    b     e    f     c    d
```

I want to feed this data into tensorflow after transforming it so the below might also be acceptable output if tensorflow would accept it?

```
col1  col2  col3
[a,b] [e,f] [c,d]
```

Below is my current code:

```
field_names = ["elo", "map", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "result"]
df_train = pd.read_csv('input/match_results.csv', names=field_names, skiprows=1, usecols=range(2, 13))

for count in range(1, 6):
    str_count = str(count)
    df_train['c' + str_count] = df_train['c' + str_count].map(champ_dict)
```

Comment: Ok, so just [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values

Comment: you need to add a better example, what hapenns with the values inside said columns ? do you want duplication or NaNs ? Personally, I think this would be a good case for a multi index column structure.in anycase see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Removed tags `machine-learning` and `artificial-intelligence` as they are not related to the question.

Comment: @Manakin I added columns to the OP.

Comment: @roganjosh I know I can use map but how do I make it expand the number of columns? I'm eventually feeding this into tensorflow so can I map them in a way where each column is an array instead of a single value per column or will tensorflow not accept that? Everytime I've run tensorflow so far it seemed to want just ints for each column not arrays of ints.

Comment: okay can you show us your own attempt - where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: I don't know what API to use to expand 1 column to multiple @Manakin or if I go the route suggested by roganjosh I don't know if tensorflow will accept the input. Using the map option this what my code would look like df_train['col1'] = expand_to_array(df_train['col1'], df_train['col2']...). If someone can point to an API for the first option or explain that tensorflow can use arrays as inputs then I can write a full piece of code.

Comment: @Manakin I added my current code, but now df_train['c' + str_count].map(champ_dict) will map to an array of floats instead of a single int like it did before

Comment: voted to re-open - once done just @ me i'll provide an answer

Comment: @Manakin do I have to do something on my end to re-open or are we just waiting for others to vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `.stack` `.map` and `.cumcount` to reshape your dataframe and index.

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase

col_dict = dict(enumerate(ascii_lowercase))
map_dict = {0: ['a','b'], 1: ['c','d'], 2: ['e', 'f']}

s = df.stack().map(map_dict).explode().reset_index()
s['level_1'] = s['level_1'] +  s.groupby(['level_1','level_0']).cumcount().map(col_dict)




df_new = s.set_index(['level_0','level_1']).unstack(1).droplevel(0,1).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_new)

level_1  col1a col1b col2a col2b col3a col3b
0           a     b     e     f     c     d
```